# Hive index rebuild too slow in compare with PostgreSQL

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to compare same functionality on my PostgreSQL data warehouse and newly created Hive data warehouse on same box with same data and same table structure . I am trying to understand Hive benefits, but... Despite the fact that data load into PostgreSQL running 3 times slower - the index creation/rebuild on PostgreSQL is 20 times faster, the index doesn't need to be rebuild every time like in Hive. 
My question is: what I am missing in Hive configuration?

My setup is:
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  aa int,
  bb string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION '/data/spaces/hadoop/hadoopfs';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/data/Informix94/spaces/postgres/myfile_big' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE  mytable;

CREATE INDEX mytable_indx ON TABLE mytable(aa) AS 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.index.compact.CompactIndexHandler' WITH DEFERRED REBUILD LOCATION '/data/spaces/hadoop/hadoopfs';

set hive.optimize.autoindex=true;
set hive.optimize.index.filter=true;

alter index mytable_indx ON mytable rebuild;

My Box is VM with 3 G ram with PostgreSQL running on it and taking ~ 1 G ram. He is serving as metadata store. I am using most recent stable versions of CentOS, Hadoop, Hive and didn't changed Hive default setting except matadata store location and statistics disabling.

The result:
index rebuild takes 4798 seconds on 260.000.000 rows or 80 seconds on 5.000.000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Hive only works well when your data doesn't fit on a single machine anymore. So the results you are seeing are expected results. So once you've collected Terabytes or Petabytes of data you'll be much happier with hive. In the use-case you describe PostgreSQL would be a much better match.